# Android Auto Backup: Transport rejected package

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I am trying to test [Android auto backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html). I am on a 7.1 device and the app manifest contains: `android:fullBackupOnly="true"`. When I issue a `adb shell bmgr backupnow <package>` command (for SO post I have replace my package name with a placeholder), I get what looks like a failure:

```
Running backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Package <package> with result: Transport rejected package
Backup finished with result: Success
```

if I change the manifest to `android:fullBackupOnly="false"` (ie use the old K/V backup) and then reissue the `backupnow` command I get what looks like success:

```
Running backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Package <package> with result: Success
Backup finished with result: Success
```

Looking at Logcat in the rejection case I see the following:

```
11-10 09:27:59.660 1683-1683/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.bmgr.Bmgr
11-10 09:27:59.669 1035-2498/? V/PerformBackupTask: Beginning backup of 0 targets
11-10 09:27:59.677 1035-2498/? D/PerformBackupTask: invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
11-10 09:27:59.685 1035-2498/? I/BackupRestoreController: Getting widget state for user: 0
11-10 09:27:59.691 1035-2498/? D/PerformBackupTask: Starting full backups for: [<package>]
11-10 09:27:59.692 1035-2498/? I/BackupManagerService: K/V backup pass finished.
11-10 09:27:59.693 1035-1699/? I/PFTBT: Initiating full-data transport backup of <package>
11-10 09:27:59.695 12554-12566/? I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Attempt to do full backup on <package>
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of <package>, skipping
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? I/PFTBT: Unbinding agent in <package>
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? W/ActivityManager: Unbinding backup agent with no active backup
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? I/PFTBT: Full backup completed with status: 0
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? I/BackupManagerService: Full data backup pass finished.
```

with these being the relevant lines:

```
11-10 09:27:59.695 12554-12566/? I/Backup: [GmsBackupTransport] Attempt to do full backup on <package>
11-10 09:27:59.697 1035-1699/? I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of <package>, skipping
```

Why is the full / auto backup failing?

Here is the full Logcat from the success (K/V) case:

```
11-10 09:31:21.750 2200-2200/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.bmgr.Bmgr
11-10 09:31:21.762 1035-2498/? V/PerformBackupTask: Beginning backup of 1 targets
11-10 09:31:21.768 1035-2498/? D/PerformBackupTask: invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
11-10 09:31:21.775 1035-2498/? I/BackupRestoreController: Getting widget state for user: 0
11-10 09:31:21.780 1035-2498/? D/PerformBackupTask: starting key/value backup of BackupRequest{pkg= <package>}
11-10 09:31:21.783 1035-2498/? D/BackupManagerService: awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{b68136a  <package>}
11-10 09:31:21.793 1035-1815/? D/BackupManagerService: agentConnected pkg= <package> agent=android.os.BinderProxy@6750684
11-10 09:31:21.793 1035-2498/? I/BackupManagerService: got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@5e82e6d
11-10 09:31:21.793 1035-2498/? D/PerformBackupTask: invokeAgentForBackup on  <package>
11-10 09:31:21.796 1908-1920/ <package> D/BackupAgent: onBackup
11-10 09:31:21.796 1908-1920/ <package> D/BackupHelperDispatcher: handling existing helper 'data'  <package>.io.DbBackupHelper@35d5ebe
11-10 09:31:21.798 1908-1920/ <package> D/BackupHelperDispatcher: handling existing helper 'prefs' android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper@6936b1f
11-10 09:31:21.800 1035-2498/? I/BackupRestoreController: Getting widget state for user: 0
11-10 09:31:21.805 2200-2200/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 09:31:21.807 1035-2498/? I/BackupManagerService: K/V backup pass finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html
says the following:

> Exceeded Quota
>
> If you see the the following messages in logcat:
>
> I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of PACKAGE, skipping
>
> --- or ---
>
> I/PFTBT: Transport quota exceeded for package: PACKAGE
>
> Your app has
>   exceeded the quota and has been banned from backing up data on this
>   device. To lift the ban, either factory reset your device or change
>   the backup account.

Comment: I saw that but the docs indicate that the quota should be 25MB per app which I should be far below.

Comment: If you install your app in an emulator, then you can check the files with:
adb shell;
su;
ls -la /sdcard/Android/data/<package>/files;
ls -la /data/data/<package>;

Comment: I have the very same problem the case is "I/PFTBT: Transport rejected backup of PACKAGE, skipping", I even tried with a new install of the app with all data deleted and still. Tried setting verbose props for the transport but I cannot get the reason for rejecting :(

Comment: @PetrNalevka same problem to me any update

Answer (score 0):

I got this same exact error, and finally found the solution:

The `targetSdkLevel` in `build.gradle` must be set to **23** or higher.

The project will compile and run fine in an emulator if `targetSdkLevel` is set to e.g. 21. But to be able to use Google Play Services as the backup destination (which I guess most of us are using), it must be at least 23.

Comment: The same problem appears still in api level 29 at least on some devices. On my Samsung SM-T585 tablet I've been able to back up my app only once, all the other times see "Transport rejected backup of ...".